# Are Purging and Embargo better than TimeSeriesSplit?

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, finance

It is well known that the classical k-fold CV does not work well when it comes to time series data. I recently found two methods called [Purging and Embargo](https://blog.quantinsti.com/cross-validation-embargo-purging-combinatorial/), which aim to modify the k-fold CV, so that there is no data leakage.

**Purging k-fold CV:**

The main idea is to 'purge' (remove) the observations in the training set, which at some point in time coincided with those in the validation set.

**Embargo:**

The idea of purging observations is amplified by embargo. Embargo removes the observations from the training set, which immediately follow the validation set.

**My questions are:**

1. Why bother doing this when you can simply use TimeSeriesSplit, which is much simpler to both understand and implement?
2. Is there any evidence that using Purging and/or Embargo produces better results?

In particular, I am interested in answering these questions in the setting of financial time series. Any references to papers and/or intuitive arguments are much appreciated.

---

For anyone interested you can also refer to [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyjmHHoMc80&ab_channel=Hudson%26Thames) on financial CV, which explains Purging and Embargo.

For those that have access, I leave the reference to the paper containing my original encounter with the methods: [doi.org/10.1016/j.eswa.2023.121012](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.eswa.2023.121012)

You can also find these methods discussed in the book by Marcos Lopes de Prado 'Advances in Financial Machine Learning'. He also talks about these briefly in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRUlSm4gdQ4&ab_channel=Quantopian).

Comment: "Any references to papers and/or intuitive arguments are much appreciated". Similarly, I'm sure we would appreciate links to the articles proposing "Purging" and "Embargo", as Googling these terms is likely to be fruitless :)

Comment: @JohnMadden Sure, the paper that I saw both the methods in can be found at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.eswa.2023.121012

Comment: The paper is not publicly accessible. Please edit your post to include a description of what Purging and Embargo are so it is understandable to other people. Thank you!

Comment: @StephanKolassa Despite what the previous comment suggested, this information can be easily Googled: 'Purging and Embargo'. I do not believe that it is correct to make the question gigantic by providing a bunch of notations and definitions (just like I do not do with TimeSeriesSplit). Everyone interested can find this info freely and the people who can answer the question are probably already familiar with the methods anyway

Comment: We’ll see how it goes to take that stance when you’re asking professionals for free consulting. Perhaps you’ll get an excellent answer.

Comment: Why not spend a paragraph on embargo and another on purging? All the references you gave us are welcome, but the post would be more self contained and easier to follow if you just spelled those terms out. That would cost you a few minutes but also save as much time for every reader (certainly more than one); they will appreciate your effort. Thank you!